# INPUT_KEYBOARD clear state of a key

Tags: c++, winapi, input

I have an accessibility C++ Windows app and the issue I'm having is I send a INPUT_KEYBOARD for the windows key (VK_LWIN) via SendInput.  Usually shortly thereafter I send a KEYEVENTF_KEYUP message and everything works great.  However, there is a rare case where after I send the first message, I do not want to send the up message, but also do not want to leave VK_LWIN in the down state.  Is there any way to reset or clear this?

Comment: Excuse my summary if its in error - you send a keydown message. Then you send a keyup message. Sometimes (for unspecified reasons) you don't feel like sending the keyup message. You want to know if you can alert windows in some other way that a key has been released. I suggest you further elaborate on the purpose or goal achieved by failing to send the keyup message. It sounds a little like an XY problem to me thus far. Further reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You cannot force the keyboard state of another process.  SetKeyboardState() can only work for your own process.  Similarly you cannot make assumptions about the keyboard state before you start injecting keystrokes.  Nor can you assume that the intended target application will receive them.

Comment: You summarized it correctly, and yes I can solve the issue another way.  I was just curious if this was possible using some sort of input command like SendInput, but sounds like it is not possible.